About adopted and progressively measurable processes (and overall measure theory)
I'm studying measure theory recently and trying to kind of 'visualize' it. Moreover, I don't really catch how adapted processes and progressively measurable processes can be actually different. The following are what I have thought. It may be wrong and if so, please let me know.
For a given set $\Omega$, what we want to do for a $\sigma$-algebra is to kind of 'partition' $\Omega$ and consider a 'power set' (just in the concept) of it. To be more precise, if $\Omega$ is partitioned into several parts so it can be given the most fundamental measures, those parts and other subsets of $\Omega$ that can be made by taking countable union of them are included in a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$.
So in this scope, a filtration can be considered as something similar to a sub-partition. For example, if $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a filtration, the basic partition made to construct the $\sigma$-algebra gets sub-partitioned as $t$ increases.
Now let $X$ be a stochastic process on a filtered probaility space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, (\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}, \mathcal P)$. When you denote by $X_t$, it means to fix time to $t$, so it can be a map with domain $\Omega$. And for a $\sigma$-algebra to contain information about a random variable means that it at least have sets that give the same value of the random variable as elements. For example, if $A(\subseteq\Omega)$ is the preimage of $1$ and $B(\subseteq\Omega)$ is the preimage of $2$, a sigma algebra must at least contain both $A$ and $B$ as separate elements to contain information, so that it can distinguish an 'where' an event which gives value $1$ or $2$ has happened (either $A$ or $B$). So now, we say $X$ is adopted if each $\mathcal F_t$ contains the information of $X$ 'at' $t$. And we say $X$ is progressively measurable if $\mathcal F_t$ contains the information of $X$ 'until' $t$. So here I don't get how they can be actually different. Since a filtration 'remembers' the structure of previous sub $\sigma$-algebras which each contain information of $X$ at that time, shouldn't it contain all the information until then, which makes it also progressively measurable? I know I'm wrong but can't really tell how in a qualitative way.
This is all for my questions. I appologize for using unprecise descriptions which might make you confused. I am struggling to get some intuition of this field (or to 'savor' what the mathematical expressions actually mean), so it might be wrong from the first line. If so, I would appreciate it so much if you help me fix it. Thank you guys all for reading:)
